# Converting a hex values to ASCII

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

What is the most 'Pythonic' way of translating

```
'\xff\xab\x12'
```

into

```
'ffab12'
```

I looked for functions that can do it, but they all want to translate to ASCII (so `'\x40'` to `'a'`). I want to have the hexadecimal digits in ASCII.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @JonClements 2.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a module called `binascii` that contains functions for just this:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('\xff\xab\x12')
'ffab12'
>>> binascii.unhexlify('ffab12')
'\xff\xab\x12'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original = '\xff\xab\x12'
result = original.replace('\\x', '')
print result
```

It's `\x` because it's escaped. `a.replace(b,c)` just replaces all occurances of `b` with `c` in `a`.

What you want is not ascii, because ascii translates 0x41 to 'A'. You just want it in hexadecimal base without the \x (or 0x, in some cases)

**Edit!!** 
Sorry, I thought the \x is escaped. So, \x followed by 2 hex digits represents a single char, not 4..

```
print "\x41"
```

Will print

> A

So what we have to do is to convert each char to hex, then print it like that:

```
res = ""
for i in original:
   res += hex(ord(i))[2:].zfill(2)
print res
```

Now let's go over this line:

```
hex(ord(i))[2:]
```

`ord(c)` - returns the numerical value of the char `c` 
`hex(i)` - returns the hex string value of the int `i` (e.g if `i=65` it will return `0x41`. 
`[2:]` - cutting the "0x" prefix out of the hex string.
`.zfill(2)` - padding with zeroes

So, making that with a list comprehension will be much shorter:

```
result = "".join([hex(ord(c))[2:].zfill(2) for c in original])
print result
```

Comment: But my original string is not escaped. It is what I said it is: `'\xff\xab\x12'`.

Comment: Oh, so if that's your original string (not escaped) I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: And I *do* want ASCII, because I need to send it as ASCII to a site.

Comment: Corrected and added explanation